# targeting frame one frame from another

Tags: html

i have main html page which have two frames frame1 and frame2. frame1 is showing tree.php page
and i want that when i click on node of tree displayed in tree.php some html or php page should be displayed in frame2. how i can achieve this???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give frame2 a name

```
<frameset cols="35%,65%">
<frame src="page1.php">
<frame src="page2.php" name="MainWindow">
</frameset>
```

And set the target of the linking node to that name

```
<a href="page3.php" target="MainWindow">
```